# How to filter using > operator and then apply groupby concept to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, pandas-groupby

How can i filter a query and then do a group by

```
df.query("'result_margin' > 100").groupby(['city','season','toss_winner','toss_decision','winner'])['winner'].size()
```

I am getting this error

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I am trying to filter where result_margin is greater than 100 then groupby with the columns specified and print records

Comment: Your column is literally `'result_margin'`? Is it possible it should be  `df.query("result_margin > 100")` instead? Or is the column actually named `'result_margin'` and the column is of dtype object not int?

Answer (score 0):

Using `'result_margin'` would treat it as a string, and not refer to the columns.

You would need to remove the quotes:

```
df.query("result_margin > 100").groupby(['city','season','toss_winner','toss_decision','winner'])['winner'].size()
```

Or if you might have columns that contain spaces, than add backticks:

```
df.query("`result_margin` > 100").groupby(['city','season','toss_winner','toss_decision','winner'])['winner'].size()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert 'result_margin' to int. Try:

```
df['result_margin'] = df['result_margin'].astype(int)
```

For the filter, I always create a new dataframe.

```
df_new = df[df['result_margin']>100].groupby['city','season','toss_winner','toss_decision','winner']).agg(WinnerCount = pd.NamedAgg(column='winner',aggfunc='count'))
```

I don't use the size method but instead opt for using the agg method and create a new column. You can also try replacing the

```
agg(WinnerCount = pd.NamedAgg(column='winner',aggfunc='count'))
```

with

```
['winner'].size
```